# How to save points without losing z dimension

Tags: qgis, ogr, 3d

I try to save Points with OGR. It works well but I lose the z dimension while saving/loading.

```
from osgeo import ogr
from osgeo import osr

shapePath="...xxx.shp"
X='1.0'
Y='2.0'
Z='3.0'

driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')

srs = osr.SpatialReference()
srs.ImportFromWkt(mySRSinwkt)

dataSource = driver.Open(shapePath, 1)
layer = dataSource.CreateLayer("points", srs, geom_type=ogr.wkbPoint)
layer.CreateField(ogr.FieldDefn("Point_ID", ogr.OFTInteger))

# Set feature fields 
feature = ogr.Feature(olayer.GetLayerDefn())
feature.SetField("Point_ID", 1)

# Set geometry
geom_wkt = 'POINT (' + X + ' ' + Y + ' ' + Z + ')'
point = ogr.CreateGeometryFromWkt(geom_wkt)
feature.SetGeometry(point)

#Point has z dimension
print str(feature.GetGeometryRef())

# Create feature            
layer.CreateFeature(feature)

# remove feature and datasource from memory
feature.Destroy()
dataSource.Destroy()

# Load
dataSource = driver.Open(shapePath, 0)
layer = dataSource.GetLayer()

# Point has no z dimension anymore
for feature in layer:
    print str(feature.GetGeometryRef())

dataSource = None
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use

layer = dataSource.CreateLayer("points", srs, geom_type=ogr.wkbPoint25D)

since ogr.wkbPoint is 2D only.

Comment: Works nicely! Ty! Do you know why they 2.5D instead of 3D to name the geometries? Because it is really confusing!